# Match the blocks

Tags: pencil-and-paper-games

This puzzle is pretty easy but sure and entertaining one. so take your pencil and start matching the columns. don't look into another answer to enjoy it.

well, what you need to do is to draw a line from each block example x to the other block x.
you need to match all the blocks v, x, y, and z.

rules: 
 1. no line should overlap each other. 
 2. no line should go outside the boundary.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is pretty fun indeed! :)

> [image]

Don't forget to read [@trolley813's concise proof](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89778/match-the-blocks/89784#89784) (and upvote it :P)

Comment: Very nice! Perhaps it'd be worth linking to the proof from @trolley813 that this answer is indeed unique?

Answer (score 17):

Took another approach...

> straight lines only [image: my Solution]

Comment: Bonus points for completely understanding the difference between "Rules as written" and "rules as intended". You rules-lawyer.

Comment: I asked this question to the 5th class grade student and he gave me this answer :P.

Answer (score 14):

Well, not strictly an *answer* (since I've found exactly the same as one already posted), but rather a *proof* that other ways are not possible:

> The lower X block lies on the boundary, without any margin (and the upper X block does so), so the X-X line will divide the whole sheet into 2 disconnected regions (since the X-X line cannot be bypassed). It's now clear that the central V block must be in one of these regions, while the central Y and Z will be in the other. So, the only challenge is to draw the X-X line keeping both Vs on the one side of it, and all other letters (Ys and Zs) on the other side. The only way to draw it is shown by @OmegaKrypton in his answer.

Comment: There are two ways of drawing YY and ZZ. Imagine YZYZ is a boundary, then it creates an 'inside' and an 'outside', and only one line can be in each partition. OK has YY on the inside of YZYZ, but ZZ could be on the inside for a different solution.

Comment: [There is a second way to solve it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89801/1955), though to be fair it does keep the Vs on the "opposite side" of the Ys and Zs. I think it's effectively the mirror image of the other answer.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: There are infinitely many different ways to solve this puzzle. Imagine drawing the solution on cappucino foam, where the floating v,y,z blocks are spoons. Now you can move the three spoons around each other, changing the paths without making the solution invalid. For mathematicians: The set of solutions (mod relative homotopy) has a free and transitive action by the (infinite) [pure braid group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Relation_with_symmetric_group_and_the_pure_braid_group) P3.

Answer (score 14):

I found a different way to solve it.

> [image: Solution]

Note that this doesn't disprove [@trolley813's proof](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89778/match-the-blocks/89784#89784) - it only shows one part of the proof is incorrect:

> "So, the only challenge is to draw the X-X line keeping both Vs on the one side of it, and all other letters (Ys and Zs) on the other side. **The only way to draw it is shown by @OmegaKrypton in his answer.**" - I believe that my answer is the mirror image of @OmegaKrypton's, so if you are considering this problem as a graph it is actually the same. It is also easy to loop the lines around z and y as many times as you want to produce images that look different but are based on the same graph: [image: Same yet different]